# Fill in Function in PictureBox in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, picturebox, fill

Is there any function to automatically fill in one of these states in brazil with a certain color, but without their neighbour state? So as an example, i have the coordinate 150x and 200y for the picturebox in c# Visual Studio. And i want that from this point everything grey that surrounds this point should turn into blue, but it should stop at the white border. Is there any function to do that, without declaring specific polygons for each state? Thanks for all Answers!

[image: Brazil States]

Comment: There is no such method, but writing one is not complicated.

Comment: The algorithm is called [Flood Fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have an idea that you can use `recursion` to traverse the pixels and modify their color.

```
Bitmap bmp;
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x = e.X;
    int y = e.Y;

    bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
    ModifyMap(x, y);
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}

// Recursion
private void ModifyMap(int x, int y)
{
    // the color info of gray part "Color [A=255, R=153, G=153, B=153]"
    if (bmp.GetPixel(x, y).ToString() == "Color [A=255, R=153, G=153, B=153]")
    {
        bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Blue);
        ModifyMap(x + 1, y);
        ModifyMap(x - 1, y);
        ModifyMap(x, y + 1);
        ModifyMap(x, y - 1);
    }
}
```

The test result,

[image]

Comment: Kyle, please never ever compare non-string types using their string representation! Never! `Color` is a struct and can easily be compared using `==` operator. For other reference types, usually `Equals` method is overridden for this purpose.

Comment: You also need to check for bounds of the bitmap, to avoid exceptions. This code also uses lots of stack space, which not always work (for large images you may get StackOverflowException). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) for alternative implementations.